# Making @mentions clickable

Tags: feature-request, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [@<name> comments should link to the named person's profile (like twitter)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9652/name-comments-should-link-to-the-named-persons-profile-like-twitter)
>   [Autolink @username in comments to most recent relevent post with #comment-123546 style anchor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37978/autolink-username-in-comments-to-most-recent-relevent-post-with-comment-123546)

Currently the @mentions in comments are not clickable:

[image: screenshot]

Is there a particular reason behind keeping them text? We should convert them to links.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9652/name-comments-should-link-to-the-named-persons-profile-like-twitter

Comment: @Mat: Though that is on making links to the profile, I'd rather it link to the comment that is being replied to.

Comment: @JeffMercado Maybe you'd rather do that, but the OP didn't specify where it should link, so it's a dupe to me. Also, how could that possibly work? You're replying to usernames, not comments -- I don't see how the system could figure out what comment specifically someone is replying to.