# Why can't we have threaded comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Can we have threaded comments on answer comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31028/can-we-have-threaded-comments-on-answer-comments) 
>   [Greasemonkey script for displaying threaded comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43055/greasemonkey-script-for-displaying-threaded-comments)

I've just read through a question on here that has a series of comments, actually a lot of comments. Because there isn't a thread mechanism on here (or StackOverflow), user's have to resort to the Twitter @person format which IMO isn't as good a solution as good old threads.

I know that StackOverflow isn't supposed to encourage threads but what we've got is users resorting to the only way to identify what/who they are replying to.

Cheers, Rob.

Comment: there's a greasemonkey script for this, link anyone?

Comment: balpha is da man: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43055/greasemonkey-script-for-displaying-threaded-comments

Comment: not surprised it's a comment but i did do a search on "threads" and nothing showed up

Comment: and how does one find the "exact duplicate"??

Comment: +1 for asking a question that needs to be asked. I don't see why it should be downvoted, even though the feature request would be denied.

Answer (score 5):

No threads for me thanks. Comments are comments. If you're having a discussion in comments **you're doing it wrong**.

Comment: Yea, discussions are for communities.  There is no community here.

Comment: That's not what I'm saying. I'm saying it's outside of scope and detracts from the purpose of the site.

Comment: The community is in the chat room :-) and by a _fantastic coincidence,_ each site's chat room is also where extended "comment discussions" should take place.

Comment: Discussions in comments are 100% fine, as long as the results of the discussion get merged into the answer and then the discussion is deleted.