# Threaded comments for site proposals on Area51

Tags: feature-request, comments, stack-exchange, area-51, site-proposal

Given that a proposed site is supposed to go through a "discussion" phase, I think there would be a benefit to implementing threaded comments to aid the discussion. It's currently rather hard to follow the flow of different topics of discussion when every comment is just sequential.

[Note - I am specifically talking about the site proposal discussions in [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/). This question is not a duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31028/can-we-have-threaded-comments-on-answer-comments) or [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46558/why-cant-we-have-threaded-comments-closed). I'm not asking for threaded comments in general on the regular trilogy sites.]

The usual argument against threaded comments that "larger comments should be posted as questions" does not work here as the only questions you can post are proposed on/off topic questions for the site, not asking questions or discussing the site proposal itself.

Answer (score 2):

The comment system should work similarly to how it does on all SE sites so that users can instantly use it effectively.

Unless this is going to be implemented on SE itself (which I don't think it should be), then it shouldn't on AFO either.

Comment: Why must it work the same if the way it works is not a good fit for what you are trying to achieve? The voting system on Area51 is different to everything else. I don't think uniformity is a good reason to implement something in a way that hampers discussion when discussion is the stated goal of a site proposal.

Comment: @Simon: Commenting is too fundamental.  For example, I was able to [create links](http://example.com/) immediately on my first AFO comment.  I was also able to @reply.  I was hesitant to vote off-topic until I understood it didn't have a negative affect on rep (this shows how something working differently can screw you up, even when it should be "obvious").  All of these are from my experience with other SE sites; you have to be very careful in changing things to work differently.

Comment: Who is calling it AFO?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? [greasemonkey script for displaying threaded comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43055/greasemonkey-script-for-displaying-threaded-comments)

Answer (score -1):

Extended discussions should be taken here (metaSO).

Comment: That will just end up disconnecting the discussions from the site proposal. If that is going to be the accepted route, we need some link from the proposal to all discussions about it on metaSO. (Perhaps this could be done with standardized tags - something similar to the "related/links" lists on existing sites, but with clear tagging so you can easily bring up a list of all discussions related to a particular site proposal)

Comment: You just have to put a link to the meta discussion in the comments of the Area51 question.  Putting extended discussion in Area51 unduly influences voters.  It is the logical equivalent of putting banners in voting booths.

Comment: Meta SO doesn't do threaded comments either. You can sorta fake it with answers, but that only goes one level deep...

Comment: We don't want to encourage discussions about specific proposals to bleed over into meta. It should all be self contained. If we need a better mechanism, it will be implemented in Area 51, most likely.